# CSS: How do I go through a nested span tag tree and select each span and assign a separate value to each?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a CSS typography experiment.
http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/pbdyt

I am taking advantages of the "em" unit cascading problem.
So in my code, you will see my HTML has multiple span tags nested together.

I came across another experiment the other day, http://codepen.io/andyhullinger/pen/ipGht
I would love to apply similar effect to my text however I am having trouble using SASS to generate separate animation-delay for each span tag. Below is my code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8{
 span:nth-child(#{$i}){
  animation-delay: $i*(0.8s/8);
 }
}
```

Obviously, my CSS selector, span:nth-child isn't working. All the span tags are using animation-delay defined in span:nth-child(1). So they are all having the same animation-delay instead of a different one.

```
<span>B
 <span>L
  <span>A</span>
 </span>
</span>
```

How do I select "L, assign a value" and then "A, assign another value"?

---

Just to be clear, this is what I am going to achieve: http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/pAsIm I can write some code to loop through the number of span tags and concatenate my selector. But I am just thinking if there is a way this can be done through CSS selector.

Comment: I can't get simple CSS styling to work with the span-in-a-span format. But if you have three separate spans, it works. Do you really need span-in-a-span?

Comment: Yea I will need to know if there is a way to do it. It is not just for this experiment, just in general, is it possible to solve this with CSS.

Comment: I got the basic styling working with putting it in a div and styling with div>span, etc. Here's the fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/qcscf/1/ - May need some brute-force programming for the loop. I'll work a bit more on it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, I have solved it in a programming way. It is simple but I just thought there might be some fancy CSS selectors out there that can do the job for me instead of relying on SASS scripts. http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/pbdyt

**This is the gist of it:**

```
$char: 8;
$string: " > span";
$store: ".btn-h1 span";

@for $i from 1 through $char{
  #{$store}{
    animation-delay: $i*(0.8s/$char);
  }
  $store: $store + $string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will amend.

Answer (score -2):

Try following css to your first example (http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/pbdyt)

```
.btn-h1{
  @include text-shadow(0 0 0 black, 0 0 1px black, 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5));
  font-size: 2em;
  color: transparent;
}

.btn-h1 > span > span > span{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  animation:btn_ghost 0.8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  @include text-shadow(0 0 0 black, 0 0 1px black, 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5));
  font-size: 1em;
  color: transparent;
}

.btn-h1 > span > span{
  @include text-shadow(0 0 0 red, 0 0 1px red, 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5));
  font-size: 2em;
  color: transparent;
}

$char: 8;

@for $i from 1 through $char{
  span:nth-child(#{$i}){
    animation-delay: $i*(0.8s/$char);
  }
}

@keyframes btn_ghost{
  100% {text-shadow:30px 0 100px black;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but have you tried the following CSS yourself. It doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the second rule, it may help

.btn-h1 > span > span > span,.btn-h1 > span{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  animation:btn_ghost 0.8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  @include text-shadow(0 0 0 black, 0 0 1px black, 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5));
  font-size: 1em;
  color: transparent;
}

Comment: Thanks but I think you have misunderstood the question. This is what I am going to achieve. http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/pAsIm If you have a better way to write this, refactoring the code, let me know.